# Setting values of a maps nested within a map

Tags: java, hashmap, nested

In one of my projects, I tried to **set** values in a nested map passed in to the parameter and return an updated map. The question is: **assuming that I didn't know the map structure, how can I set values in a given path in a nested map**?

I tried to do just that. I attempted to recursively call the *set* method but to no avail, instead of returning {age=1, human={lives=3, deaths=2}}, the method either returned {deaths=2} or `null`. However, please note that this is one of my many innumerable tries.

Here's one of my methods (other methods were deleted):

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static Map<Object, Object> setNested(YamlParser parser, List<String> paths, String key, Object value, Map<Object, Object> previousMap, int loops) {
        Object found = parser.getObject(paths);
        if (!(found instanceof Map))
            return previousMap; // path is not nested
        Map<Object, Object> theMap = (Map<Object, Object>) found;
        theMap.put(key, value);
        // .... ?
        System.out.println(theMap);

        return setNested(parser, paths, key, theMap, theMap, loops + 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A version with adding all the missing intermediate maps is even simpler:

```
    private static Map<String, Object> setNested(Map<String, Object> map, List<String> keys, Object value) {
      String key = keys.get(0);
      List<String> nextKeys = keys.subList(1, keys.size());
      Object newValue;
      if (nextKeys.size() == 0) {
        newValue = value;
      } else if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
        newValue = setNested(new LinkedHashMap<>(), nextKeys, value);
      } else {
        newValue = setNested((Map<String, Object>) map.get(key), nextKeys, value);
      }
      Map<String, Object> copyMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(map);
      copyMap.put(key, newValue);
      return copyMap;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not see what the `YamlParser` is good for in this example and I do not know what exactly you want to do. I think, it is about making a new map where the intermediate maps and the final (leaf) map have been copied and the new leaf map has a new value.

If this is not exactly what you need, you are free to modify it. Maybe it gives you a hint how to implement your own method:

```
public class Test {

      private static Map<String, Object> setNested(Map<String, Object> map, List<String> keys, Object value) {
        String key = keys.get(0);
        List<String> nextKeys = keys.subList(1, keys.size());
        if (nextKeys.size() == 0) {
          Map<String, Object> copyMap = new LinkedHashMap<>((Map) map);
          copyMap.put(key, value);
          return copyMap;
        } else if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
          return map;
        } else {
          Map<String, Object> copyMap = new LinkedHashMap<>((Map) map);
          Map<String, Object> nextMap = (Map<String, Object>) map.get(key);
          copyMap.put(key, setNested(nextMap, nextKeys, value));
          return copyMap;
        }
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> map1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Map<String, Object> map2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map2.put("lives", 3);
        map2.put("deaths", 2);
        map1.put("age", 1);
        map1.put("human", map2);
        System.out.println(map1);

        map1 = setNested(map1, Arrays.asList("human", "deaths"), 7);
        System.out.println(map1);

      }
    }
```

Note: This method can insert new keys at the lowest level maps, but not at the intermediate maps.

Comment: Hey thanks! I don't know how you figured it out easily.